# Dynamic Module Parameter in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I need to set dynamic module params based on the other selected paramts. E.g:
Theme : Style 1, Style 2, Style 3, Style 4, Style 5 etc.

If Style 1 is chosen, I want to display the configuration options of style 1 only as they are the only ones that apply.
Style 1 > Color, Style 1 > width, Style 1 > height etc.

I do not want to have too many visible fields (that do not apply to the module anyway). Is there a way I can add javascript to hide other fields or is there some other solution to this problem.

Need solution for Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 too.

Comment: Have you got the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla 1.5 this is not possible (as far as I know). I always try to order the fields as logic as possible and use the advanced tab.

As for 2.5, there is a description here: http://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Joomla-Tips/creating-custom-parameters-in-joomla-16.html